# Wrap socket.on as a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io, promise, angularjs-service

I am making a service, with a function `init` as `resolve`. First, it creates a folder with the id of the connection, then it writes some default files inside. The folder (ie, the id of the connection) should be recorded, which is the purpose of `this.dir`.

The following code calls well `initDir`. However, it does not call `initFiles` (ie, `alert("here")` is not called). I guess it is because `initDir` was not made well as a promise.

Does anyone know how to amend it?

```
this.files = [ ... ... ];

this.dir = "public/tmp/default/";

this.initDir = function () {
    var socket = io.connect();
    return socket.on('id', function (id) {
        var dir = "public/tmp/" + id + "/";
        return $http.post('mkdir', { dir: dir })
            .then(function () {
                this.dir = dir;
            })
    })
} 

this.initFiles = function (dir, files) {
    return $http.post('writeFile', { dir: dir, file: files[0] })
        .then(function (res) {
            $http.post('writeFile', { dir: dir, file: files[1] })
                .then(function (res) {
                    console.log("saved 2 files")
                })
            })
    })
}

this.init = function () {
    return this.initDir() 
        .then(function (res) {
            alert("here");
            this.initFiles(this.dir, this.files)
        })
}
```

On the server side, it just sends the connection id after every connection:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('id', socket.id);
}
```

**Edit 1:** Following the answer of @epiqueras , I modified the code. The following code calls `inside init`, however it does not call `inside initDir`....

```
var dirP = "public/tmp/default/";

this.initDir = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        alert("inside initDir")
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('id', function (id) {
            var dir = "public/tmp/" + id + "/";
            $http.post('mkdir', { dir: dir })
                .then(function () {
                    dirP = dir;
                    resolve(dirP)
                })
        })
    })      
} 

this.init = function (files) {
    alert("inside init");
    return initDir
        .then(function (dir) {
            alert("before initFiles");
            this.initFiles(dir, files)
        })
}
```

**Edit 2:** after changing `initDir.then` to `this.initDir().then`, I have the following code. It shows well `inside init`, `inside initDir`, `before initFiles`. However, it does not show `inside initFiles` or write files.

```
this.initDir = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("inside initDir")
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('id', function (id) {
            var dir = "public/tmp/" + id + "/";
            $http.post('mkdir', { dir: dir })
                .then(function () {
                    dirP = dir;
                    resolve(dirP)
                })
        })
    })      
}; 

this.initFiles = function (dir, files) {
    console.log("initFiles: " + dir);
    return $http.post('writeFile', { dir: dir, file: files[0] })
        .then(function (res) {
            $http.post('writeFile', { dir: dir, file: files[1] })
                .then(function (res) {
                    console.log("saved 2 files")
                })
            })
    })
}

this.init = function (files) {
    console.log("inside init");
    return this.initDir().then(function (dir) {
        console.log("before initFiles " + dir + JSON.stringify(files));
        this.initFiles(dir, files)
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because socket.on does not return it's callback's return value.

Try wrapping the code with a promise and resolve inside the callback instead of just returning.

```
initDir() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        socket.on.....
            $http.post.....then(resolve)
    }
}
```

Make sure you are returning the new Promise and that you are resolving the final value you wish to wait for.

Comment: Do you think if we assign a value to `this.dir` inside `initDir`, it will be recorded in the service? Is it possible and a good practice to return a promise and a value (ie, `dir`)?

Comment: "this" inside the ".then" callback won't refer to the same object as the outside "this.dir". "this" refers to the object the function is called on behalf of. In this case it will probably be called by your promise implementation's handler object. It would be better to just use a global or static variable.

Comment: Or use an arrow function if your runtime or build tool supports ES6. Arrow functions preserve the "this" of where they are defined.

Comment: you mean "global or static variable" of the service?

Comment: Just define it somewhere where it will be in scope everywhere you need to use it.

Comment: @SoftTimur you are calling .then on the initDir function, not the promise it returns. Change it to initDir().then.....

Comment: Do you get an error message? It sounds like your socket is not working.

Comment: In the front-end, i got nothing. In the back-end, I have a message `Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html`, is it relevant?

Comment: Ah, also a message in the front-end: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: I would get rid of the socket connection and http request and just resolve a fixed value to rule off a promise error. Then I would see if the sockets are connected by console.logging on the server in the "connected" callback. If all of that works the error is in the http request.

Comment: I changed `this.initDir` to `= function () { return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { alert("inside initDir"); resolve("lalala"); }) }`. It still just shows `inside init`, but not `inside initDir`... I think it is `new Promise` which does not work...

Comment: Are you dismissing the alerts? Alerts stop program execution. They won't all come up at the same time.

Comment: I changed `alert` to `console.log`, it is the same thing... I think it is just `new Promise` which does not work...

Comment: You would get an error saying Promise is undefined.

Comment: I don't see that message... I am considering using some promise libraries, maybe `$q`?

Comment: You don't need a library if your runtime supports native promises. You are calling initDir, but it doesn't exist. You should be calling this.initDir. Look at your console errors.

Comment: I got it... actually we need to define `initFiles` as a private method, and change `this.initFiles(dir, files)` to `initFiles(dir, files)` inside the `resolve` function.

Comment: You had the same "this" scope problem.